# Une traduction de l’interjection néerlandaise « hehe »

Tags: traduction, néerlandais, interjections

Je cherche à traduire un mot que l’on utilise chez moi, « hehe ». À vrai dire, je ne sais pas comment ça s’écrit, je pense voir qu’il y a plus de façons de l’épeler.

On l’entend quand quelqu’un trouve que quelque chose dure trop longtemps. Quelqu’un qui était presque au bout de sa patience, et qui est tout d’un coup satisfait pourrait le dire. Le mot exprime du soulagement et un peu de mécontentement à la fois.

Par exemple, à la fin d’une longue averse de pluie : « Hehe, voici une occase pour sortir de notre maison ».

Quand un repas tarde, et on est heureux de se mettre à table, on peut dire quelque chose comme « Hehe, je que je suis ravi que la nourriture soit prête maintenant, je meurs de faim. »

D’ailleurs, c’est une interjection. Ce mot ne s’emploie jamais à l’écrit, (sauf quand un écrivain veut calquer ce que quelqu’un dit.)

Le mot apparaît surtout devant les propos, le propos sert assez souvent à expliquer qu’est-ce qui embête celui qui parle. Quand ça ressort déjà des circonstances, on a tendance à l’omettre.

J’espère que ça suffit pour trouver un mot qui remplit la même fonction en français. Si vous pensez à une locution figée qui le traduit mieux, je vous prie de la donner parce qu’elle pourrait également répondre à cette question. Si vous donner une interjection, décrivez comment on utilise sa voix, cela peut être important.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke, Merci! Il y a une seule chose que je ne saisis pas : Pourquoi faut il remplacer « importer » par « être important » ? Je pensais jadis qu'« importer » était pareil.

Comment: « importer » c'est un verbe qui est apparenté avec le mot « important », effectivement. On a un expression « peu importe » qui signifie l'inverse de « peut être important ». Par contre, tu aurais pu écrire « cela m'importe » (« je trouve que cela est important » ou « je suis intéressé par cette information »). http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/importer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'expression « **Ah, bah enfin !** », aussi transcrit « **Ah, ben enfin !** »  me parait bien correspondre à la description.

Elle n'est employée qu'en français parlé et traduit à la fois un soulagement et un léger mécontentement.

« **Ouf** », « **Ah** » et « **Enfin** » suggérés ailleurs peuvent aussi rendre l'idée de contentement et de soulagement mais ont besoin d'une intonation spécifique pour traduire l'aspect irritation.

Comment: Hein ? C'est *ah*, pas *ha*.

Comment: @Gilles Oui bien sûr, merci !

Comment: Je dirais que la traduction serait juste « Enfin ! » Ou encore « Ouf ! C'est fini. ».

Comment: @jlliagre, Je crois maintenant que vôtre tournure marche mieux que ce que Gilles suggère. Cependant, vous me dites peu sur le son de la voix de celui qui parle. Pourriez-vous m’enseigner quel ton convient ici, à l’instar de Gilles ?

Comment: Le « Ah » est long, c'est le même que celui qu'a déjà bien décrit Gilles. « bah enfin ! » est prononcé comme un seul mot.

Comment: @ jlliagre, À vrai dire je doute encore un peu, car ce que vous dites est un peu flou. Y-a-t il une façon d’enregistrer ça, ce serait vraiment pratique ! Ça exige trop de temps de d’approfondir et d’expliquer l’intonation d’un mot à l’écrit.

Answer (score 7):

L'interjection correspondante en français est *[ah](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ah)* (TLF sens I.A.2 ou I.A.3). Dans cet usage, on prononce forcément le A long, et on souffle souvent de façon audible : une superposition de [aː] et d'un soufflement. De plus, le ton est forcément descendant (de l'aigu vers le grave). On écrit quelquefois *aah* ou *ahh*, voire *aaah* ou *ahhh*, pour marquer la longueur, mais cela reste [très minoritaire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Aah%2FAh%2CAaah%2FAh%2CAhh%2FAh%2CAhhh%2FAh%2CAahh%2FAh&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28Aah%20/%20Ah%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Aaah%20/%20Ah%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Ahh%20/%20Ah%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Ahhh%20/%20Ah%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Aahh%20/%20Ah%29%3B%2Cc0).

L'interjection *ah* a d'autres sens, qui peuvent être marqués par le contexte ou par la prononciation. Par exemple, dans le *ah* qui marque la compréhension ou le soulagement, on ne souffle pas particulièrement, et le ton est montant puis descendant. Dans le *ah* qui marque l'étonnement, on ne souffle pas non plus et le ton est montant.

Le ton ne laisse en général pas d'ambiguïté sur le sens de l'interjection. On peut toutefois la renforcer par un adverbe ou autre tournure. Dans le sens de *hehe*, on dit souvent « Ah, enfin ! ». Lorsque le *ah* n'est pas seul, il est en général plus court, et les différences de prononciation qui distinguent les différent sens du *ah* seul sont nettement moins marquées.

Comment: Il y a aussi « Ouf! »

Comment: @AlexisWilke Mais *ouf*, c'est le soulagement. On l'utilise quand quelque chose de désirable arrive, mais seulement s'il y avait un risque significatif que cela n'arrive pas, pas si on a juste dû attendre quelque chose qui devait arriver tôt ou tard.

Comment: Oui, encore que quand quelque chose semble interminable (conversation avec une belle mère...) « Ouf! Je croyais que ça ne s’arrêterait jamais. » Peut-être que l'on utilise Ouf! incorrectement dans l'Est de la France...

Comment: @Alexis Wilke, Aux Pays-Bas, on utilise « oef », et ce que Gilles dit me fait croire que ce mot équivaut tout à fait à le mot français. D’ailleurs,« oef » n’exprime jamais du mécontentement où j'habite

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin, _ouf_ exprime un soulagement, _ah_ un contentement.

Comment: Vraiment ? Le mot « hehe » c’est en fait une façon courte de dire « Ça m’énerve que ça durait si longtemps, mais je suis heureux que l’attente est terminé. ». Ce premier composant ne devrait pas manquer.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin « Ah » inclut le premier composant, au moins s'il est dit sur le bon ton (descendant).